# How to plot multiple corresponding labels in dendrogram that is truncated at an upper level?

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

When dendrogram is truncated at a set level (using `truncate_mode = 'level', p = 5`), leaf nodes in the visualization may correspond to multiple objects instead of singletons. The default behavior of the original function is to label those leaf nodes with the number of objects.

Is there a way to plot all corresponding labels instead of counts? I suspect 'leaf_label_func' parameter of 'scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram' could be utilized to this end but I was not able to make it work.

A sample code and part of its output is below.

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show_dendrogram(Z, labs, txt):

  plt.figure(figsize=(10, 30))
...
  
  dendrogram(
      Z,
      labels = labs,
      truncate_mode = 'level',
      p = 5,
...
    )
  plt.show()
```

[image: Sample output]